# Why can I not open a React web app in a browser through an ingress when deploying it in a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: reactjs, docker, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have a very simple React web app (using Argon Dashboard Pro Template) deployed in a Kubernetes cluster. The Docker image of it works locally as well as in the cluster when exposing it via nodeport. But exposing it via NGINX ingress doesn't work, although the ingress itself is tested for other services and applications which expose REST endpoints. The content of the web page is not built correctly, because some js files are not found, although this is the case when they are exposed via nodeport.

Kubernetes Deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: react-deployment
  namespace: support
  labels:
    app: react
    stage: dev
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: react
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: react
          image: fmaus/react-test:argon
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
              name: react-port
          imagePullPolicy: Always
      restartPolicy: Always
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: react
```

Kubernetes Ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: react-ingress
  namespace: support
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
      more_set_headers "Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8";
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /test(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: react-service
            port:
              number: 3000
```

Kubernetes Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: "react-service"
  namespace: support
spec:
  selector:
    app: "react"
  ports:
    - port: 3000
  type: ClusterIP
```

This Code can also be found in my GitHub Repository: https://github.com/fmaus/react-kubernetes-test

To reproduce the problem, just apply these Kubernetes resources to a cluster and try to reach the web app through a browser via ingress (http://host/subpath). I have the resources deployed here: http://c105-164.cloud.gwdg.de:31600/test
The error messages can be visited in the console of the browser (F12 when using Firefox):

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://c105-164.cloud.gwdg.de:31600/static/js/bundle.js”. subpath:61:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://c105-164.cloud.gwdg.de:31600/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js”. subpath:61:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://c105-164.cloud.gwdg.de:31600/static/js/main.chunk.js”.
```

I use Mozilla Firefox and the following NGINX ingress controller: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/

Comment: Just a note, as professionaly I use a lot of K8s and React as well, but we never deploy a React app in a K8s cluster. Usually you only deploy backend servers like NodeJS api's in a K8s cluster. For a React front-end I would strongly advise to simply deploy it in a S3 bucket with cloudfront enabled.

Comment: @Robert-JanKuyper Thanks! Unfortunately we cannot do that. Is there any special config needed to expose s3 buckets via nginx-ingress? In the end those buckets need to provide some kind of web server the traffic gets sent to, so the solution might be similar.

Comment: When using s3 buckets you need to configure cloudfront, what will act the same as ingress does in k8s. Cloudfront allows you to connect a hostname to files stored in the bucket and make them public available. Cloudfront handles all the load and traffic for you. It is much cheaper as well, and also easier to maintain. See the docs: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/.

Comment: @Fabian, Have you got the solution for the same, as  I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have two issues in place here:

- You set the content type to javascript, so the html is not interpreted correctly by the browser. F.e. http://c105-164.cloud.gwdg.de:31600/test/index.html is shown as source
- You need to make sure the resources are referenced including the sub path, or a 404 will result

For example

```
<script src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script><script src="/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/main.chunk.js"></script></body>
```

Needs to load the bundle from /subpath/static/js/bundle.js since it is an absolute link.

Comment: But how do I reference the resource correctly? The nginx-ingress is just sending traffic to another nginx which is running in the same pod that the react is located in. That nginx does not know anything about the existence of the parts of the url the ingress strips away.

Comment: You could set a base-href in the index.html for example

Comment: Thanks! Your advice with href was pretty helpful. The argon template uses an env variable in this href section. After deleting the content-type annotation and setting the env variable for the argon template correctly, the problem could be solved.